# MATLAB: Find numeric columns in a cell array

Tags: matlab, dataset, cell-array

I would like to use gplotmatrix on a dataset data, which contains mixed data (numeric and strings). However, gplotmatrix works on numeric data, so I need to convert my dataset to a matrix. As far as I know, the only way is to do this is through

```
C=dataset2cell(data)
X=cell2mat(C)
```

However, the second command throws an error, because C contains non-numeric columns. Is there a way to find which columns of a cell array are purely numeric?

Comment: It works! I got the `cellfun(@isnumeric,C)` part working, but I didn't think of postprocessing it with `all`. Thanks! Any references to learn this stuff?

Comment: Yes, google for "cellfun matlab", "function handle matlab", etc. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) with `@isnumeric` function handle -

```
numeric_cols = find(all(cellfun(@isnumeric,C)))
```

Related useful pointers -

- [function_handle](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html)
- [Anonymous Functions](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)